# Tensorflow Estimator API Input Tensor Names

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

When using an estimator in tensorflow and passing the inputs using `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_function()`, what are the names of the tensors being created for the features and labels' inputs.

If I print out the name of all the placeholders in my graph I get the following:

`name: "enqueue_input/Placeholder"
name: "enqueue_input/Placeholder_1"
name: "enqueue_input/Placeholder_2"`

However, the shape of those tensors were not specified so I cannot tell which is which or why there are 3 of them instead of only one features and one labels tensors.

I realize this question was also asked here: [TensorFlow: What are the input nodes for tf.Estimator models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335699/tensorflow-what-are-the-input-nodes-for-tf-estimator-models)

But no one answered.

Comment: I didn't use numpy_input_function, I used tf.data.Dataset. But it works. See if my answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335699/tensorflow-what-are-the-input-nodes-for-tf-estimator-models/51063972#51063972

Answer (score 1):

`numpy_input_fn` has two important arguments: `x` and `y`. `x` is a dictionary that matches the names of feature columns to arrays containing feature data. `y` is an array that contains the labels for the features in `x`.

For example, the following code associates the feature named `x_coord` with Label 1 when the value is 0.5 and with Label 2 when the value is 1.2:

```
train_input = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x_coord": np.array([0.5, 1.2])}, y=np.array([1, 2]))
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this does not answer my question. I understand how the `input_fn` works. I do not understand what the estimator calls the input tensors.